# continuously interacting with .exe file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script in python to start an .exe and continuously interact with it.
for example:
My .exe file is a calculator (calc.exe) with options 
1.add 2.sub 3.multiple 4.division.

i am able to start the .exe file , but i don't know how to pass the option numbers(or variables)  to it.
Can anyone help ? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to 'continuously' interact with it, I'm assuming you need to read/write the stdout/stdin during the runtime of the program.

For this purpose, check:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Example:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['program.exe'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
command='1\n'
p.stdin.write(command)
response=p.stdout.read()
```